# Do I need a tear down method when mocking in Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a simple unit test where in I test a DAO. I mock the dependency and inject it into the subject through the constructor.
Do I need a tear down? Does Mockito test exit at the same state it entered the setup method? Please also explain.

```
@Mock
private PersonDAO dao;

@Overide
public void setup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sut = new PersonResource(dao);
}

@Test
public void testUpdate(){
    when(dao.findNameById(1)).thenReturn("Abhinav-before");
    sut.update(1, "Abhinav-after");
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the code? It would simplify things a lot

Comment: <!-- language: lang-java -->
`
@Mock  
private PersonDAO dao;  

@Overide  
public void setup(){  
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);  
sut = new PersonResource(dao);  
}  

@Test  
public void testUpdate(){  
when(dao.findNameById(1)).thenReturn("Abhinav-before");  
sut.update(1, "Abhinav-after");  
}'

Do I need a tear down for the dao mock?

Comment: @AbhinavGandhi Don't post relevant code in comments. Please edit your question and include the code you've provided

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're pulling in other state-driven resources, such as a cache, or a temp file, you don't need to tear down any resources when mocking.

A mock object is just an object; it doesn't have or maintain anything to external services.  It will get garbage collected just like any other object you have in your test.  Depending on how you're injecting the mock, it's recreated for every test run, anyway.

Now that you've provided a little bit of code, had you used the `@Before` annotation, you would be sure that both the mock gets injected *before* each instance of the test run.  As it stands, that test probably doesn't compile; I can't imagine a scenario in which you would have that test extend another test that has a `setup` method.

<sup>(And if you do, please don't.  You'll only hurt yourself.)</sup>

Lastly, **assert something** in this test.  You're not asserting anything, so it'll always pass unless you assert something to be true about the state of your test object.

With that bit out of the way, if you use `MockitoJUnitRunner` instead, you don't require the `initMocks` piece, but this is only applicable if this is your *only* runner as JUnit can't support multiple runners.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonResourceTest {
    @Mock
    private PersonDAO dao;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonResource testObject;

    @Test
    public void testUpdate(){
        when(dao.findNameById(1)).thenReturn("Abhinav-before");
        testObject.update(1, "Abhinav-after");
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say - It is recreated for every test, is the mock destroyed at the last test in the test suite?

Comment: The mock - along with any other objects you've instantiated - are destroyed upon completion of each individual test.  Then, they're recreated at the beginning of the next test.  That's what I've observed from my experiences and interactions with it, at least.

Comment: Note that it may be true for JUnit as this framework crreates a new instance for every test method. However with TestNG ideas are different, and a single instance of the test is created, and a mock contains invocation, stubs, etc. hence state, in this case yes one must have a tear down method `@AfterMethod` with `Mockito.reset(mock1, mock2, ...)`

Comment: Also note since Mockito 1.10.8+, there's a [JUnit rule](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html), that can replace the role of the runner. Note that the runner and the rule offer more safety to isolate mock usage issues as they are validating internal state of mockito between test methods.